# How to select records from table1 which doesnt have records in table 2 between certain dates

Tags: t-sql

I have customers table and a another one for the sales activities associated to them (phone calls, emails ecc). 
What I need is to know is which of those customers haven’t been contacted (without activities) over the last 30 days for example.

Here is what I’m trying to do:

```
SELECT crm_customers.id, crm_ customers.companyname
FROM crm_ customers 
LEFT JOIN crm_activities on crm_customers.id = crm_ activities. Customerid
WHERE crm_ activities.createddate < (getDate() – 30)
```

The problem is that it returns the customers with activities older than 30 days even if they have more recent activities. I need to get only the customers without any sales activities in the last 30 days
Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT crm_customers.id, crm_customers.companyname
FROM crm_customers 
LEFT JOIN crm_activities 
  on crm_customers.id = crm_activities.Customerid
 and DATEDIFF(DD, crm_activities.createddate, getdate()) < 30
where crm_activities.Customerid is null
```

This is a case of condition in the join is different than condition in the where

For speed I would suspect the join over the subquery.  It gives the query optimizer more option to optimize.  Does not required a distinct.  Assume crm_activities.Customerid is indexed this is joining on the index.  With the subquery it would use the index to create the list but output of the subquery is not indexed.

Will depend on you datar.  I had a big table to test on.

Query plans are different.

On a loop join it was dead heat 
On a hash join twice as fast 
On a merge join ten times as fast

If none are excluded then it will be a dead heat.
Where it will show up is if many are excluded (have been contacted in the last 30).

Comment: This one works great too. Another option with same results. I wonder if there is a performance difference.   thanks

Comment: @DaKodar I'm curious about the performance comparisson. Would you share them when (if) you have them?

Comment: @DaKodar see my comment.  The subquery takes an index out of play on the join.   Check out a query plan on the two.

Comment: @barranka Sure. I'll run some tests with large data and let you know the results ;)

Comment: Again based on indexes on crm_customers.id and  crm_activities.Customerid

Answer (score 0):

This might help you: Use a subquery:

```
select 
    cust.id, cust.compayname
from
    crm_customers as cust
    left join (
        select 
            * 
        from 
            crm_activities 
        where 
            createddate >= (getDate() - 30)
    ) as act on cust.id = act.customerId
where
    act.customerId is null
```

This way you *exclude* all customers with activity within the last 30 days.

---

You may want to clean up this a bit more, by doing something like this:

```
select 
    cust.id, cust.compayname
from
    crm_customers as cust
    left join (
        select distinct 
            customerId 
        from 
            crm_activities where createddate >= (getDate() - 30)
    ) as act on cust.id = act.customerId
where
    act.customerId is null
```

It's the same basic idea... the only thing is that this second option just returns the Ids of the customers with activities. I think that this may optimize the outer `where` clause, but it may have a performance impact in the subquery (no free lunch)

Comment: Hint: You probably want to reverse the sense of the test - exclude customers that *have* had activity recently